# Raspberry pi 2 IoT

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, iot

I would like to ask how to connect GSM module [pgsm-1](http://pandatron.cz/elektronika3/pgsm_predstaveni_pin.gif) to Raspberry pi 2 running Windows IoT core. We are supposed to connect it to the RasPi 2 via pins [RXD and TXD](http://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/73950-102-4-309126/GPIO_Pi2.png) which are [labeled as reserved](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/images/PinMappings/RP2_Pinout.png) by Microsoft now. How could we do that?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com is where you should be asking that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use any 'supported' USB-to-Serial adapter to connect to the GSM module. Altough the list of supported hardware offered by MS is a bit of a mess...

I use one with a "Silabs CP2102" chip, but it requires some re-plugging from time to time since it seems to freeze on Win 10 IoT Core...